# In the windows API, is there a generic method which will give you the appropriate HTTP proxy for a URL?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, winhttp

I'm writing an application intended for distribution around the world. I recently discovered a method of WinHTTP:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384097(VS.85).aspx

This can decode any Netscape-style PAC file (in Javascript) and tell me the correct proxy to use for any URL I might want to use.

That's all great, but I've noticed that some of our company sites use a proxy configuration with a "ins" file ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171783 ) - and the WinHTTP service seems not to understand this style of configuration.

So is there an alternative method I can use? Surely there must be a function somewhere which understands all of Microsoft's many and varied configuration standards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The INS format is for IE, try [WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384096(VS.85).aspx) to get that configuration.